# The name of my checkbox can not be resolved

Tags: java, checkbox, selected

I have a problem with my checkbox. When I try to read the state of it the name of it can not be resolved.

```
JCheckBox checkbox1 = new JCheckBox("Test");
    checkbox1.setBounds(6, 59, 121, 23);
    frmTree.getContentPane().add(checkbox1);

public void Checkbox() {

if (checkbox1.isSelected()) {
Sytem.out.println("Selected");
        }}
```

Comment: Please post enough code that others can compile it and re-create your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//add this
checkbox1.setSelected(true);
```

Change your Checkbox function to this code:

```
//Try using boolean in your condition
//Get the selection state of the checkbox
boolean selected = checkbox1.isSelected();
if (selected) {
    System.out.println("Selected.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Selected.");
}

frmTree.getContentPane().add(checkbox1);
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you are using c#. I'll edit my code.

Comment: it stil the same "checkbox1 cannot be resolved". I dont get it.

Comment: Well in that case, the code you have show us in your question is not the code you are actually using.  Laurence's answer is correct.  Edit your question to show us what you are really doing.

Answer (score 1):

hey instead of "isSelected()" try using "isChecked()".

Comment: where did you call the method "Checkbox()" .. paste the full code here or visit the following ..
http://www.javatpoint.com/android-checkbox-example

Comment: Its on the top while the JCheckBox checkbox1 = new JCheckBox("Test"); is on the bottom

Comment: There is no isChecked method listed in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBox.html).